# Clean Create React App's cache when importing graphql files

Tags: reactjs, graphql, create-react-app, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using create-react-app and react-app-rewired to customize my configuration. Here is my `config-overrides.js` :

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra')
const rewireInlineImportGraphqlAst = require('react-app-rewire-inline-import-graphql-ast')

module.exports = override(
  rewireInlineImportGraphqlAst,
  fixBabelImports('antd', {
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true
  }),
  fixBabelImports('ant-design-pro', {
    libraryDirectory: 'lib',
    style: true,
    camel2DashComponentName: false
  }),
  fixBabelImports('lodash', {
    libraryDirectory: '',
    camel2DashComponentName: false
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: {
      '@primary-color': '#308AC9',
      '@font-size-lg': '15px',
      '@menu-inline-toplevel-item-height': '34px',
      '@menu-item-height': '34px'
    }
  })
)
```

[The `react-app-rewire-inline-import-graphql-ast`](https://github.com/detrohutt/react-app-rewire-inline-import-graphql-ast) is used to parse graphql files during build time, so I'm able to import graphql ASTs like this using Apollo :

```
import React from 'react'
import editUserMutation from '../graphql/editUser.graphql'

const Editor = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={editUserMutation}>
    {mutate => ...}
  </Mutation>
)
```

Here is my graphql file :

```
mutation($email: String!, $password: String!, $name: String!, $job: String!, $website: String!, $bio: String!, $avatar: String) {
  editUser(email: $email, password: $password, name: $name, job: $job, website: $website, bio: $bio, avatar: $avatar) {
    id
  }
}
```

Now, here is the issue : I first made a mistake in my graphql file, writing `_id` instead of `id`, so GraphQL rightfully complained

> Cannot query field "_id" on type "User"

But then after correction, GraphQL still complains about `_id`. I found out by logging my imported `editUserMutation` AST that the old flawed version **was still somehow cached and used.**

I tried a lot of things :
- Restarting `yarn start` on the entire project
- Rename then rename back my graphql file
- Clean my browser cache

Nothing helps.

What's the issue here ? Thanks.

**EDIT** : I got rid of the issue by removing the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling my dependencies. So there might be some sort of very persistant cache in that folder, does anybody know where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the underlying [plugin](https://github.com/detrohutt/babel-plugin-import-graphql):

> Each time you modify a GraphQL file, the node_modules/.cache/babel-loader folder must be cleared for the changes to take effect. I recommend prepending the relevant script in your package.json and rerunning the script when you change a GraphQL file:

```
    {
      "scripts": {
        "start": "rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader && node index.js"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I did look everywhere except there... Thank you very much.