# React Apollo - GraphQL files are not updating/reflecting the changes

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, react-18

I am upgrading my react app to version 18, its still in progress but i am facing a weird behaviour with graphql queries. I am using React Apollo to manage all the frontend store data and graphql macro to load all graphql files. Earlier also every time we make any changes in *.gql. We used to restart the server as those files are not by default watched(hot reload) in CRA config but currently even if i had made any changes, added or removed any fields from gql query/mutations. My application is still trying to load the previous queries. Even restarting the server is not helping. Sometime it works and most of the time it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by clearing the cache which was being generated in node_modules. Also i have updated the start script by appending the cache clear command.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader && react-scripts start",
}
```

Reference - [Clean Create React App's cache when importing graphql files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783964/clean-create-react-apps-cache-when-importing-graphql-files?rq=1)